# how to resolve the issue of getting rotated image on some devices after capture from camera in android

Tags: android

I created a custom camera activity in my Android app but am having issues with images being rotated 90 degrees when I displayed on the next activity based on which device it's taken on. This only happens on particular devices.I want to figure out this problem.

Comment: mImageView.setRotation(angle)

Comment: setRotation is not work all the time like in samsung galaxy s4...so you should give rotation or crop image option after capturing an image....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code, pass it your path:

```
try {
        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(picturePath);

        orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1);

        Matrix m = new Matrix();

        if ((orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180)) {

            m.postRotate(180);
            Log.e("in orientation", "" + orientation);
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(thumbnail, 0, 0,
                    thumbnail.getWidth(), thumbnail.getHeight(), m,
                    true);

        } else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) {

            m.postRotate(90);
            Log.e("in orientation", "" + orientation);
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(thumbnail, 0, 0,
                    thumbnail.getWidth(), thumbnail.getHeight(), m,
                    true);

        } else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) {

            m.postRotate(270);
            Log.e("in orientation", "" + orientation);
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(thumbnail, 0, 0,
                    thumbnail.getWidth(), thumbnail.getHeight(), m,
                    true);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```